# Get API Platform documentation running in an existing Symfony 3.4 appliation

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, api-platform.com

Following the advice from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56315554/how-to-install-api-platform-in-existing-symfony-3-4-application-without-flex), I ran the following in my existing Symfony 3.4 application's home directory:

```
composer require api-platform/core v2.2
```

... after which composer spit out a bunch of green messages confirming successful installation.

However, when I visit `http://localhost:8443/` as suggested [here](https://api-platform.com/docs/distribution/#its-ready), I get 'can't establish a connection'.

My Symfony app is still running normally when I go to `http://localhost`. Are there additional steps required to get the API Platform documentation running?

Comment: Try `http://localhost/api/`what do you get in that case?

Comment: Thanks. I get `No route found for "GET /api/"`

Comment: Can you show your configurations for api-platform/core?

Answer (score 3):

(For Symfony2/3)

Use this package with composer:
composer require api-platform/core

Configure the bundle manually in AppKernel.php:

```
$bundles = [
// [...]
new ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Symfony\Bundle\ApiPlatformBundle(),
];
```

Add this in your app/config/routing.yml

```
api:
resource: '.'
type: 'api_platform'
prefix: '/api' # Optional
```

If needed, add your specific configuration in app/config/config.yml

```
 api_platform:
 title: 'specific name'
```

(complete configuration https://api-platform.com/docs/core/configuration/)

I hope it will help.